# (Is there an easy fix?) Imported model bones are all rotated 90 degrees

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, import

I am learning how to model in blender, and am trying to make a character for my game. Instead of making a character from scratch I imported a default model from unity and am modifying it.

I noticed the bones in the rig are all rotated as shown below. Should I just delete all the bones and redo it myself, or is there an easy way to fix them? They seem to be working correctly. (I don't think I would be able to redo the eyes and mouth rigging)

Thanks! :)

[image: bones are all rotated]

Comment: I am just redoing it. I tried alt + R as someone suggested to me elsewhere but it didn't work.

Comment: there are addons and scripts that can do that and correct rotated bones it depends on the format though.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/222330/rotate-all-bones-in-rig-by-90-degrees