# Rotate all bones in rig by 90 degrees

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

I want to create an animation with a rigged model, but it appears as if the bones are all rotated 90 degrees:

[image: Rig with bones rotated 90 degrees]

This is best visible in the tail; I would expect the tip of the left bones meet the head of the right bones, as is the case with most rigs I've seen. For example:

[image: "Regular" rig]

While the rig does work correctly and is posable, I'd like to rotate the bones back so they look like you'd expect. Of course this can be done manually, but is there a way to do them all in one go?

Comment: Have you imported the rig? Here is a similar question https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/222291/107598.

Comment: @Blunder thanks for the link, tweaking the import settings solved it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be solved by tweaking the primary and secondary bone axis in the armature tab when importing. (In case of a .fbx)